# How to give values as well as the percentage in the google bar chart?

Tags: javascript, php, charts

In the google bar chart how to add percentage with numeric values?

Comment: Add `%{numeric_value}`

Comment: Check [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)